# Best website for giving details of a book mentioned in a Statement of Purpose

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, united-states, statement-of-purpose

I want to mention a book in my SOP/PS and would like to provide a link so that the reader can easily get more details about the book instead of googling it. What would be the ideal website for this purpose: Amazon, google books, publisher's page, author's page etc. or is it best not to include a link at all in case the SOP's are usually read on paper?

Comment: FWIW, I probably wouldn't click through in the context of serving on an admissions committee.  I'd expect your application package to stand alone.

Comment: Seconding @ScottSeidman: I'd not be willing to do any clicking... your application should stand by itself. Indeed, in some cases, admissions or hiring committees are _forbidden_ to look on-line!

Comment: *If* you need to include a link (see answers below on why you shouldn't), publishers page or authors page should be fine. I would however prefer an ISBN or DOI (if the book has one), or a link to the book entry in a national library catalogue. Don't link to Amazon or Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest no link at all for several reasons. Most important is that you don't want the reader to go off somewhere else while reading your SoP. You want them to focus on what you write.

Also, as you note, you don't know how the SoP will be read (paper, electronic...). And, you probably have a word limit and might find a better use for the few words it would take for the link.

You should consider that such statements are likely to be viewed, at least in part, as examples of your writing.

A commercial site (Amazon,...) would probably be incorrect.

I would only consider it if the work were obscure. It is likely however, that if it is important to what you say, then others in the field can probably find it easily enough.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, only mention it in the PS if that book is truly important for your development (Do you have a good reason to justify that to yourself?). If the book is popular, it is probably unnecessary to provide extra information on the details of the book. If it is obscure, as Buffy answered, it is not a terrible idea to mention the details in the essay. However,  you have to take into account that you only have limited space for the PS. You have more to say than what you have learnt from a book. The committee has limited time for each applicant too and probably will not look at it.

It is better if you can provide evidence that you truly learnt something from the book, and produced something as the direct result of reading the book. In fact, that was what I did. The course I wanted to take was not available, so I instead bought an advanced book for that course, self-studied, built a small project based on what I learnt and rewrote code for all algorithms in the book in another programming language. I mentioned it in "**Miscellaneous**" section of my CV instead.

Also, it is good to have some other supplement documents.